# HTML table cell size not right when cell is empty

Tags: html

I am wanting a consistent size for my table cells. I am having a problem when a cell is empty. It looks like this:[image]

```
            <table style="width:100%" class="fixed">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h4><u><b>PushPin Description</b></u></h4>
                    {% for description,  url_value in zip(pushPinDescription, url) %}
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><a href={{url_value}}><b>{{description}}</b></a></font> </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </th>

                <th>
                    <h4><u><b>Corkboard</b></u></h4>
                    {% for title in corkboardTitle %}
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><b>{{title}}</b></font> </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </table>
```

However, when the value in description is filled. all of the boxes align correctly. How can I make it so that the boxes are all aligned, even if the description is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add   for empty cell or you can add 
.list-group-item {
    min-height: 50px;
}

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
 <table style="width:100%" class="fixed">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h4><u><b>PushPin Description</b></u></h4>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><a href={{url_value}}><b>&nbsp;</b></a></font> </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><a href={{url_value}}><b>{{description}}</b></a></font> </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><a href={{url_value}}><b>{{description}}</b></a></font> </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><a href={{url_value}}><b>{{description}}</b></a></font> </li>

                </th>

                <th>
                    <h4><u><b>Corkboard</b></u></h4>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><b>{{title}}</b></font> </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><b>{{title}}</b></font> </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><b>{{title}}</b></font> </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><font size="2"><b>{{title}}</b></font> </li>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </table>
```